# How to deal cards according to probabilities?

Tags: python, random, probability

#### Moved to [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/514006/314457)

I am trying to write a function that deals cards to players given a probability distribution. This can be thought of as a dealer who is cheating and wants to give certain cards to certain players but doesn't want to be obvious.

For example with a three card deck and three players:

|  | Ace | King | Queen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Player 1** | 0% | 66% | 33% |
| **Player 2** | 33% | 33% | 33% |
| **Player 3** | 66% | 0% | 33% |

Choosing a card based on weights is not the problem. The problem is that when a card is chosen then that card cannot be at another player.

Choosing one by one can lead to situations when the remaining player has 0% probability to get the remaining card. In the above example - what if **Player 1** gets a **Queen**, **Player 2** gets an **Ace**. Then **Player 3** cannot get any card as his **King** probability is 0%.

---

One way I tried is to deal the cards per player. Then check if there are duplicates and if there are I deal again till there are no duplicate cards. The resulting distribution does **not** follow what I want.

The reason for this (in the example above) is that the re-dealing would happen more often for **Player 1** getting **Queen** because the chance of a duplicate in that case is 66% unlike when **Player 1** gets a **King** (33%). This skews the resulting distribution.

---

Another way that I tried is to deal **Player 1**'s card. Then remove that from the possible **Player 2** cards and deal a card out of that for **Player 2**. The card for player 3 is the remaining card. This I saw is clearly stupid because **Player 3** even had **King**s which he should have with 0% probability.

Here is the code for the second version I mentioned:

```py
import random

# returns a list of three cards:
# 0 is an Ace,  1 is a King and 2 is a Queen
def sample(probabilities):
    p1_card = random.choices([0, 1, 2], weights=probabilities[0])[0]

    p2_possible_cards = [0, 1, 2]
    p2_weights = probabilities[1][:]

    p2_possible_cards.pop(p1_card)
    p2_weights.pop(p1_card)

    p2_card = random.choices(p2_possible_cards, weights=p2_weights)[0]

    if 0 not in [p1_card, p2_card]:
        p3_card = 0
    elif 1 not in [p1_card, p2_card]:
        p3_card = 1
    else:
        p3_card = 2

    return [p1_card, p2_card, p3_card]


probabilities = [
    [0.0, 0.666666, 0.333333],
    [0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333],
    [0.666666, 0.0, 0.333333],
]

distribution = [
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
]

for _ in range(100_000):
    for card, dist in zip(sample(probabilities), distribution):
        dist[card] += 1

distribution = [[card / 100_000 for card in player] for player in distribution]

# distribution is:
# [
#    [0.0    , 0.66734, 0.33266],
#    [0.50087, 0.16556, 0.33357],
#    [0.49913, 0.16710, 0.33377],
# ]
# which is not even close to probabilities
```

Comment: You say that the deck consists of three cards? I think using the probability distribution can only work when dealing the first player's card. After that, other players are forced to take cards.

Comment: I agree that it's a logical problem. But there are some impossible cases in what you want: imagine that the first player get a Queen and the second a Ace: so all that remains in the set of cards is the King, but the third player has a probability of "0.0" for the King.

Comment: Yes I understand. I'm implicitly asking: "what would be your desired output in this particular case"?

Comment: You should compute each permutation probability and sample according to those probabilities. The time complexity might be exponential as you are dealing with all permutations

Comment: @Rivers The sample function should never return [Queen, Ace, King]. Or you could say it should return that with 0% probability.

Comment: @pLOPeGG This is just a simplification for my actual problem in which the table is pretty big so I don't think that is an option here.

Comment: Right now I don't see any simple way to make it scale, maybe an approximation would suffice ?

Comment: The programming is not the issue here. Why not ask this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @djvg would that or math.stackexchange make more sense for this?

Comment: Well, https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic mentions "probability theory", so that would be my first choice. But I would not include any code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done a very good observation with the following:

> Another way that I tried is to deal Player 1's card. Then remove that
> from the possible Player 2 cards and deal a card out of that for
> Player 2. The card for player 3 is the remaining card. This I saw is
> clearly stupid because Player 3 even had Kings which he should have
> with 0% probability.

And I would even say it's not stupid at all.
You will have to deal with the fact that every card can only be dealt exactly one time (no less and no more). Starting at player 1, everything is fine and she gets a king with 66% probability and a queen with 33% probability.
Then when going to player two, the distribution for all three cards might be uniform, but the supply isn't. It is not possible to deal a king with 33% probability if the king isn't available.

The situation for player two is conditional on the outcome of player one. I think in this case it's most clear when you simply consider all possible cases:

1. king, 2) ace
2. king, 2) queen
3. queen, 2) ace
4. queen, 2) king

Draw this like a tree and put probabilities on all branches, you will then come to the conclusion that the following probabilities apply and will give you a uniform distribution of the three cards for player two:

```
deal player two ace, given that player one has king: 1/2
deal player two queen, given that player one has king: 1/2
deal player two ace, given that player one has queen: 0
deal player two king, given that player one has queen: 1

probability for queen: (2/3) * (1/2) = (1/3)
probability for king: (1/3) * 1 = (1/3)
probability for ace: (2/3) * (1/2) + (1/3) * 0 = (1/3)
```

You can add player three in a similar fashion, the problem just becomes bigger.

EDIT: The probability you are looking for in your question is infeasible. Player three can not have a 0% chance of getting a card when there is a positive chance that this card is the only one left to give player three. The only way to avoid this is to change the order in which you deal cards. But taking into the account 'dealer' context, there is usually no free choice in order.

Comment: Right but I imagine this tree that we would use for sampling would grow exponentially large as we increase the number of player and cards. Is there really no better way to do this do you think?

Comment: With this algorithm you can reach dead ends. With @Hadus example, if P1 gets Queen and P2 gets Ace, you end up with no possible choice.

Comment: Probably yes, but I can't think of it right now.
@pLOPeGG luckily so, because in fact the very example that you give proves that the distribution Hadus is looking for, is invalid.